# Fix the link for the "Abusive to Others" moderator message template

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderator-tools, help-center

This template reads

> There's a relevant section from the
>   [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/help) that reads:
>
> Be Nice. Treat others with the same respect you'd want them to treat
>   you. We're all here to learn together. Be tolerant of others who may
>   not know everything you know. Bring your sense of humor.

The FAQ link points to https://stackoverflow.com/help.  Please change it so that it points to https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fixed and should be out in the next build.